# clarification regarding "connection oriented"

Tags: networking, tcp

I just want to check my understanding of terms,I was stuck at the term "Connection-oriented".In case of virtual circuits which works at layer 3,connection establishment is nothing but reservation of resources like buffers.and it identifies path by combination of (VPI and VCI).I was under impression that term "connection oriented" means same in case of TCP which works at transport layer and does 3 way handshake for connection establishment. But after reading  https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6307/does-tcp-use-virtual-circuit-model
which mentions "But TCP connections still aren't circuits, because they don't reserve bandwidth during connection on every switch between the two nodes." I am confused.Am i missing some important terminology or concept?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look here: http://courses.iddl.vt.edu/CS1604/15-Lesson_14/04-Connection-Oriented_vs_Connectionless.php

Comment: Your citation says that virtual circuits work at layer *two,* the layer *below* TCP.

Answer (score -1):

In case of TCP, 'connection-oriented service' means having a session established in the transport layer. In case of TCP, data transmission is guaranteed. You have acknowledgements in TCP. These are some reasons why it is called 'connection-oriented'.